# How to get scroll direction on specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page have a div called #product. I need to fill progress bar when user scroll in #product div. How can I do it using jquery. Thanks.

```
if (/* page scroll to #product div */){
var scrolled = ??? //percentage of scroll on div
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get current scroll position with this:

```
currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()
```

where 100% scroll is:

```
maxScroll = this.scrollHeight
```

Then your current **progress percentage** will be:

```
(currentScroll / maxScroll) * 100
```

Use this code:

```
$('#product').bind('scroll', function() {
  var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight(),
      maxScroll     = this.scrollHeight;
  var scrolled = (currentScroll / maxScroll) * 100;
  });
```

**[See example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/8fup8tju/)**

**EDIT:**

To let the div come to top on browser scroll add:

```
$(document).bind('scroll', function() {
  $('#product').css({ position: absolute; top: 0; });
});
```

Comment: How can I get the div comes to top when user scroll. Thanks for reply bro.

Comment: What do you mean with "comes to top"? Is it [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/8fup8tju/2/)?

Comment: There is a div on bottom of page. When scroll the page the div (#product) comes to browser top. Then the script should be worked.